# Is it possible to not limit the upper value of a regex range for a repetition of a character (Infinite)?

Tags: javascript, regex, infinite

Is it possible to not limit the upper value of a regex range for the repetition of a character?  I'm not sure if this is possible.  I'm using `infinity` as a placeholder in this example:

```
let lowerLimit = 2; // Or any value
let regex = RegExp ("[\n]{" + lowerLimit + ",Infinity}", "g");
```

Comment: `[\n]+` for `1 or more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a comma with no value as max quantifier.

```
{n,}
```

With your code

```
let lowerLimit = 2; // Or any value
let regex = RegExp ("[\n]{" + lowerLimit + ",}", "g");
//                                          ^^
```

Comment: Thank you!  It is working exactly as I want!  Will accept after SO lets me!